# How to make a post request with Post data ( A single param of type Int) through the browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-mvc-routing, restful-url

I am using the `Web API 2` in my Web application which also uses `MVC` individual user accounts. So all the controllers has `[Authorize]` attribute. I would like to test my Web API method if it’s working fine but I can’t use the tool POSTMAN for testing as login functionality of the app is just restricting. I tried logging in to the site from postman but failed, that cookies and all just blown my head. I want to make that post request through the browser by passing the post data from URL itself. I tried multiple ways but seems I am going wrong somewhere, Needed some assistance.

**The Routeconfig file:**

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name:"AttendanceRoute",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{gigId}",
        defaults: new { gigId = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

**The controller:**

```
namespace GigHub.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class AttendancesController : ApiController
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext context;
        public AttendancesController()
        {
            context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("api/Attendances/Attend/{gigId}")]
        public IHttpActionResult Attend([FromBody] int gigId)
        {
            var attendance = new Attendance
            {
                GigId = gigId,
                AttendeeId = User.Identity.GetUserId()
            };
            context.Attendances.Add(attendance);
            context.SaveChanges();

            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

The requests I tried; 
(1)http://localhost:50702/api/attendances/Attend/5
(2)http://localhost:50702/api/attendances/Attend?gigId=5

When I tried the above requests I am getting the following error.
**(1)The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'.
(2) No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI**

I followed Web API 2 tutorial by microsoft and searched other resources but for posting the data and for testing people are using postman & sending data in the form body. When Posting params for GetRequest as query string is working fine then can't we do the same for PostRequest as well?

Comment: Simple & quick answer: (1) You can't use GET request for blatantly marked `HttpPostAttribute` method, (2) The parameter marked with `FromBodyAttribute` comes only from the entity body of the incoming `HttpRequestMessage`, not from URL request.

Comment: Thanks for the info @TetsuyaYamamoto, So do you think is there any way around to my query?

Comment: If you want to make GET request from `Attend`, simply remove `HttpPost` & `FromBody` attributes, but I still figuring out what you want to do with GET request which inserting data to database - something which should handled with POST request.

Comment: Addendum: I think this doc may help you find out the issue => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-1. If you're POST-ing from an HTML form & using jQuery, you can use `$.post('api/Attendances/Attend', { "": $('#gigId').val() });`

Comment: yep, I used the jquery to post the data and checked. thank you @Tetsuya Yamamoto.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to still pass the body and test from POSTMAN you can make a little tweak to your controller and be able to achieve it. 
Just mark your controller with the [AllowAnonymous] attribute, which would make your controller and all the action methods inside to be accessible by anyone! and your controller would look something similar to this

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class AttendancesController : ApiController
{
    private ApplicationDbContext context;
    public AttendancesController()
    {
        context = new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

Now simply what you can do is, in the POSTMAN give the URL and select POST from
the list of HTTP METHODS and in the body just give

```
{ "gigId" : "<Your Id Here>"}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Bhadhri, thanks for the answer. To make any changes to the app, first I need to login then like you said I can apply the "Allowanonymous" attribute on to the respective controller to allow post request.